# How to fetch and return record with total number of records in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working with rest api using codeigniter,I want to fetch records + total records + per page records,but not worked for me 
Here is my function in controller

```
<?php 
public function search_shop()
{
    $users['rec'] = $this->Model_users->find_shop($_POST);
    if($users['rec']!="")
        {
            $responseJSON = array("Status" => true,"Result" => $users['rec']);
            header("content-type:application/json");
            $response = json_encode($responseJSON);
            echo $response; 
        }
        else
            {
                $responseJSON = array("Status" => false,"Message" => "There is no matching record");
                header("content-type:application/json");
                $response = json_encode($responseJSON);
                echo $response; 
            }   
}
```

And here is my "find_shop" function in model,How can i fetch all records with total number of records and per page records ?

```
public function find_shop()
{       
        $add_data['page_number'] = ($this->input->post('page_number') && !empty($this->input->post('page_number'))) ? $this->input->post('page_number') : NULL;

        $add_data['search'] = ($this->input->post('search') && !empty($this->input->post('search'))) ? $this->input->post('search') : NULL;     

        $records="10";  
        $mins="10";
        if($add_data['page_number']=="" || $add_data['page_number']=="0" || $add_data['page_number']=="1")
            {
                $starting_row="0";
                $last_row="10";
            }
        else
            {
                $last_row="9";
                $cd="1";
                $lim="10";
                $starting_row=$add_data['page_number']*$lim-$last_row-$cd;
                $last_row=$add_data['page_number']*$records-$cd;
            }
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('shop s');
        $this->db->like('shop_name',$add_data['search']);
        $this->db->or_like('city',$add_data['search']);
        $this->db->limit($last_row,$starting_row);      
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
            {
                $row = $query->result_array();
                return $row;
                return $query->num_rows;
            }
        else
            {
                return false;
            }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This, Hope it helps**
in the Controller please test this after model related changes

```
$users = array();
$users = $this->Model_users->find_shop($_POST);
echo'<pre>';print_r($users);die;
```

in the Model, There is a mistake in the return, You cannot do two return at the same time

```
$query = $this->db->get();
if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
{
    $data = array();
    $data['row'] = $query->result_array();
    $data['total_records'] = $this->db->count_all_results('shop');
    $data['per_page_records'] = $query->num_rows();
    return $data;
}else{
    return array('row'=>array(),'total_records'=>'0','per_page_records'=>'0');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your if condition like this:

```
        $records="10";  // This is records per page showing
        if ($add_data['page_number']=="" || $add_data['page_number']=="0" || $add_data['page_number']=="1")
        {
            $starting_row="0";
        } else {
            $starting_row = ($add_data['page_number'] - 1) * $records;            
        }
```

You need to set limit and offset of query. For example: limit 0, 10: this will show first 10 records. Here 0 is starting point and 10 is the length of records which you want to show. 10 will always be same as you are showing 10 records. Limit 10, 10: it will show records from 10 to 19. hope it clears your doubt.